# Windows compatible passwords in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a script that takes windows compatible passwords and uses them to create an account for the user on the computer with that as their system password.

I have run into an issue where if I escape them and pass it to create the account it is taken literally. Single ' and double " quotes are allowed in windows.

Example user enters hello'world 
escaped as hello\'world and stored in the database as hello\'world. 
user inputs hello'world login. 
Computer expects hello\'world as the correct password, user can not login.

Adding code:

```
echo "somepass" | sudo -S /Applications/Setup\ user.app/Contents/Resources/nugget "Joe User" "juser" "ju$er'Pa$$".345"
```

Essentially the account for the user is created, another admin account has to be used and the password set from the gui where ju$er'Pa$$".345 is entered and from there the user can login fine.

Comment: Then you're escaping them wrong.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yes that was obvious to me. I would not be asking if I knew the correct method.

Comment: Please add the script/code you are using. And don't crosspost the same question on several SE sites.

Comment: @BobR Your description of the problem and the code you're posting do not appear to be the same: you describe a problematic script asking for input from a GUI and then post a single line with mismatched quotes that hard-codes a password. Can you please post the actual script you're having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want? (Obviously you need a safe method to retrieve the password, either from `read` input or by reading from a file handle or pipe).

```
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ read -r password ; printf '%q\n' "$password"
ju$er'Pa$$".345
ju\$er\'Pa\$\$\".345
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $
```